# How can I edit my own indicator in tradingview, I have mistakenly set overlay as true instead of false

Tags: tradingview-api, indicator

How can I edit my own indicator in tradingview, I have mistakenly set overlay as true instead of false. In the script of my indicator Anit Momentum Indicator, Overlay = False but I have mentioned it as True.

I tried to edit the code but it is not allowing me to do so.